# How to view the password onchange of checkbox? OpenERp/Odoo

Tags: passwords, odoo, onchange

How to view the password onchange of checkbox?

`<field name="username"/>
 <field name="password"  password= "True"/>
 <field name="checkbox"/>`

(checkbox - type=boolean) So if i check on the checkbox i need to view my password entered in the password field..

how do i do it ?